# Converting std::vector<char> to char* causes defective characters

Tags: c++, vector, char

I have a function in my code called `buildPacket` that takes some parameters, and converts them into a `char*` and adds them together using a `std::vector<char>` and at the end returns the result as a `char*`. The problem is that after I convert the vector to a `char*` all characters become a weird character.

I tried using other ways of converting the vector to a `char*`, like with using `reinterpret_cast<char*>`. When I print the contents of the vector from inside the function, I get the expected result so the problem is with the conversion.

The function's code:

```cpp
char* buildPacket (int code, std::string data)
{
    char* codeBytes = CAST_TO_BYTES(code);
    std::vector<char> packetBytes(codeBytes, codeBytes + sizeof(char));
    size_t dataLength = data.size() + 1;
    char* dataLengthBytes = CAST_TO_BYTES(dataLength);
    packetBytes.insert(packetBytes.end(), dataLengthBytes, dataLengthBytes + sizeof(int));
    const char* dataBytes = data.c_str();
    packetBytes.insert(packetBytes.end(), dataBytes, dataBytes + dataLength);

    return &packetBytes[0];
}
```

The `CAST_TO_BYTES` macro:

```cpp
#define CAST_TO_BYTES(OBJ) static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&OBJ));
```

The intent of the function is to take the input and build a packet out of it to send through a socket later on, the packet's format consists of a 1-byte long code, 4-byte long data length and data with variable length.

The input I gave it is `code = 101` and `data = "{\"password\":\"123456\",\"username\":\"test\"}"`

This is the result I am getting when printing the characters: `▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌`

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the help, I've returned a `vector<char>` at the end as suggested and took a different approach in converting to values to a `char*`.

Comment: you are casting a `int` to a `char*` using the ominous `CAST_TO_BYTES` macro. Could you add more context because it is missing.

Comment: I added the macro and some more context

Comment: Your first problem (and [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)) is your double typecast. You shouldn't have to cast to `void*` to cast to `char*`.

Comment: The one obvious error is that you return a dangling pointer.

Comment: "the packet's format consists of a 1-byte long code, 4-byte long data length" -  if that is the specification, then use that. Don't use `sizeof(int)` as a hidden, fragile way to write `4`.

Comment: @Quentin: Please don't put answers in comments

Comment: @MSalters I didn't examine the code closely enough to know whether there's something else wrong or not. And if that's it, then it falls into the "typo/cannot reproduce" VTC category. Just my rule of thumb though.

Comment: I've tried to fix the problem by returning the vector but there is another problem now, I've edited my question with more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to something inside of a local variable. You should change your code to have your `vector<char>` alive outside of your `buildPacket` function (such as by returning it instead of the `char*`).

Comment: I tried returning the vector and then creating a new `char*` and copying the contetns to there but it only shows 2 characters for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You might try this solution. I thing using STL makes it more clearer what you are trying to achieve. There was also an undefined reference in your code, that could lead to unpredictable crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// Better return std::vector<char>
char* buildPacket(int code, const std::string& data)
{
    auto result = data;
    result.append(1, static_cast<char>(code));

    char* ret = new char[data.size() + 2];
    ret[data.size() + 1] = '\0';
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), ret);

    return ret;
}

std::vector<char> buildPacketStl(int code, const std::string& data)
{
    std::vector<char> ret;
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
    ret.push_back(static_cast<char>(code));
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << buildPacket(65, "test") << std::endl;; // 65 -> A
    auto stl= buildPacketStl(65, "test"); // 65 -> A
    std::copy(stl.begin(), stl.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: As the `delete[]` comment already shows, this is not a good idea. We have containers for a reason; `buildPacket()` should return one.